# How to simulate a option tag selection inside a rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, nokogiri

[The rankings page of the WTA website](http://www.wtatennis.com/singles-rankings) shows a list of the first 100 tennis players. 
The `<option>` tag is used with a `<select>` tag to present a list of options, so that the user can select the players ranked between the 101 and the 200 positions and so on (by groups of 100 players).

I would like to use `Nokogiri` to scrape information from this page. 
For the first 100 players I can use the original web address. However, the url does not change when the user selects different ranges of players, although I was used to add `/pag/101` `/pag/201` `/pag/301` and so on to the aforementioned web address. The trick works, however the new urls are not much reliable. I often receive a `HTTPError: 504 Gateway Time-out` error.

So I though there might be the possibility to stay on the original address and simulate the selections from the option tags.

Probably the website uses `Ajax` to refresh the information on the page. 
I noticed a `<div class="ajaxLoader">` element with web inspector, before the page was refreshed.

I found the xPath expression of the `<option>` tags' contents:

```
//div[@id='jump1']/div[@class='jump-to']/select[@class='rankings-rank-change']/option[@value='1']
```

Changing `@value` selects different options.

I wonder if there is any way to trigger these values from the page and make an Ajax call inside a rb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the developer tools and checking the `Network` tab, you can see that when you change the option inside the select, the page triggers an ajax call that fetches other results.

One strategy to parse this information is:

- Get the number of options from the select
- Iterate through it making an ajax call for each page
- Parse the results from the ajax result

The URL is http://www.wtatennis.com/fragment/wtaTennis/fragments/assets/rankings/rankingsData/type/SINGLES/date/02022017/pag/{page} where you need to change `{page}` the the number inside the loop.

The code should look like this:

```
make request to first page: http://www.wtatennis.com/singles-rankings
parse the first 100 results, get data
get the number of pages from the select
make request to i page: http://www.wtatennis.com/fragment/wtaTennis/fragments/assets/rankings/rankingsData/type/SINGLES/date/02022017/pag/i
  parse results from this one
  next index on loop
now you have all the data
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you get that URL? I noticed it contains the date. You may think that it is not a fixed URL, but any combination of 8 random numbers seems working.

Comment: When i selected the first option in the select, that was the url.